# Prolog printing false when it should be returning a value

Tags: list, prolog, minimum

So basically I'm trying to find the second minimal value in a list, and the problem is that mino and secondMin return false, instead of numbers. When I do minlist(List, Min) manually, it returns Min = number, but I can't get sec to take on that value. Instead, it stays false. Can anyone help?

Second Minimum

```
secondMin(L, Min2):-
    minlist(L,Min),
    delete(L,Min,Li),                   %no prob ver
    mino(L, k),                 %return k as the 2nd minimum of L
    Min2 is k.                  %Min2 is k.
//////////some code here////////////

mino(List, sec):-

    sec is minlist(List, Min).              %min 2 is the minimum of Li
```

Comment: `sec` is a constant, not a variable etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read a tutorial or get a textbook. Only arithmetic "functions" return values, all other predicates simply use one of the arguments for output if called in that mode.

So something like

```
minlist(List, Min)
```

instead of

```
Min is minlist(List)
```

It is a bit strange because you do it correctly several times at the start of the predicate and then suddenly you start doing it wrong.

As for "second smallest number in a list", this might be easier:

> Second smallest element is the list is the second element in the sorted list.

```
second_smallest(List, SS) :-
    sort(List, [_,SS|_]).
```

This breaks down if the list is not ground, but so does your original attempt.